# Integration with multiple constants

Tags: integration

**Question:**

$$\int \frac{ax^2-b}{x\sqrt{{c^2x^2-(ax^2+b)^2}}}\ \text dx$$

**My approach:**

I can't understand whether I should integrate it normally or use a trigonometric function.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I can't get an idea.

Comment: You refer to $K$, but there is no $K$ in your expression. What is the relevance of $K$ here?

Comment: @Théophile it would be the constant of integration for example C is generally the constant of integration.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer But of what relevance to your question is the name of the constant of integration?

Comment: @Théophile change it if you find it unsuitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$I =\int\frac{(ax^2-b)}{x\sqrt{c^2x^2-(ax^2+b)^2}}dx = \int\frac{ax^2-b}{x\cdot x \sqrt{c^2-(ax+\frac{b}{x})^2}}dx$$

So $$I = \int\frac{a-\frac{b}{x^2}}{\sqrt{c^2-(ax+\frac{b}{x})^2}}dx$$

Put $\displaystyle \left(ax+\frac{b}{x}\right) = t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \left(a-\frac{b}{x^2}\right)dx = dt$

$$I = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2-t^2}}dt = \arcsin\left(\frac{t}{c}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$I =\arcsin\bigg(\frac{ax^2+b}{cx}\bigg)+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: The answer is just yours but the numerator and denominator is opposite.Interchanging your numerator and denominator gives the correct answer.